# How do I allocate space for elements in vector for type T?

Tags: rust

```
fn test<T>(arr: &mut [T]) {

    let vector=vec![] //what can I do here so that I have vector as vec with same size as arr and of type T.

}

fn main() {
    let xs = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    test(&mut xs);
}
```

Is there any solution if I enforce T to have Default trait?
I should be able to randomly access the created vector, not push serially.

Comment: What will be the value of the newly created elements? Clone of `arr`? Some default value? Uninitialized (requires `MaybeUninit` and unsafe code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this. If you can enforce that `T: Default` you can use [`resize_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize_with)

```
fn test<T: Default>(arr: &mut [T]) {
    let v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
    v.resize_with(arr.len(), Default::default);
}
```

Otherwise, you can enforce that `T: Clone` and use [`resize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize) with a provided initial value for the elements:

```
fn test<T: Clone>(arr: &mut [T], initial: T) {
    let v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
    v.resize(arr.len(), initial);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity) method

```rust
fn test<T>(arr: &mut [T]) {
    let vector : Vec<T> =  Vec::with_capacity(arr.len());
    ...
}
```

Mind that it doesn't allocate the elements, it just makes the underlying buffer big enough for `N` elements without extra re-allocations.

> I should be able to randomly access the created vector, not push serially"

Another easy way allocating the elements if they are `Clone`, is simply use the `vec!` macro:

```rust
fn test<T: Clone>(arr: &mut [T], item: T) {
    let vector : Vec<T> =  vec![item; arr.len()];
    ...
}
```

Comment: In the question they say _"I should be able to randomly access the created vector, not push serially"_ which seems to imply that they don't want the capacity set but the actual length of the vector.

Comment: @cdhowie, `How do I allocate space for elements in vector for type T?` is what is answered. I would rather see another question, or change the title. Anyway, I added an extra version that complements your answer too :)

Comment: Last excerpt should maybe read `let vector : Vec<T> =  vec![item; arr.len()];` ?

Comment: indeed @6005, changed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [`vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.vec.html) macro can accept a two-arguments form where the first one is an element that will repeated, and the second is the number of repeated elements.

It would look like something like this:

```
fn test<T: Clone+Default>(arr: &mut [T]) {
    let vector = vec![T::default(); arr.len()];
}
```